# Can Postgres SQL function transforms be applied to array types?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, numpy, plpgsql

I'm attempting to do some numerical processing on Array types in Postgres.  I found I'm able to use the Numpy library within Postgres PL/Python but the operation runs too slowly for my purposes and much slower than they would in Python directly or using a C extension.

My suspicion is that there may be overhead to go from Postgres Array Type -> Python List -> Numpy Arrray and then do the reverse on return.

To test (and potentially fix) I'm trying to build a C extension which would skip going through the Python list and convert directly from Postgres Array to Numpy Array and vice-versa.

I've created a C extension which defines the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION arr_to_np(val internal) RETURNS internal LANGUAGE C AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'arr_to_np';

CREATE FUNCTION np_to_arr(val internal) RETURNS real[] LANGUAGE C 
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'np_to_arr';

CREATE TRANSFORM FOR real[] LANGUAGE plpythonu (
    FROM SQL WITH FUNCTION arr_to_np(internal),
    TO SQL WITH FUNCTION np_to_arr(internal)
);
```

The module loads without problems but when I try to use it in a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn (a integer[])
  RETURNS integer
  TRANSFORM FOR TYPE real[] 
  AS $$  return a $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

I get: *ERROR:  transform for type real language "plpythonu" does not exist*

My guestimate is that the transform is attempting to be applied to the base "real" type and not the array.  Is there any way to specify transforms specifically for arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is not possible.

In `lsyscache.c` (`get_transform_oid`) it converts the type of a transform to its base type which strips off the "array" and so the function is always applied to the underlying type.

Going to see if I can put together a patch to allow this behaviour, but currently (postgres <=11.0) you cannot create custom transforms for array objects.